# Sharepoint Calendar Issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calendar

When i am adding event in share point 2010 calendar programmatically, I need to refresh 2 time calendar. After that event is added to calendar.. Plz help me. Its urgent..

code:

SPList calendarList = web.Lists["Calendar"];
.
.
.
.
item.update();
calendarList.update();

Comment: I'm not sure what you try to accomplish. Is it refreshing the page for the user after making some changes in code?

Comment: I have made one webpart. I have added it on calendar. So I have wrote code on page load.

Comment: What you could try to do is SPUtility.Redirect(...) or write a client script block to the page where you refresh it

Comment: No I manually refresh my page. I not use any script block or nothing else..

Comment: So it's no problem to refresh? You want to make some changes to the listitem, but you can't see them?

Comment: Problem is that Whenever i add event and after that I refresh page manually. Event is not added in Calendar list. I have checked All Items View. No any event is added.

Comment: Can you paste more of your code then? It's not so clear what you're trying to do...

Comment: SPListItem Item = calendarList.Items.Add();
                            Item["Title"] = "Event";
                            Item["Description"] = "Desc";
                            Item["EventDate"] = "10/9/2012";
                            Item["EndDate"] = "10/10/2012";
                            Item["Location"] = "ABC";
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                            Item.Update();
                            calendarList.Update();
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I have solved my Problem.....

Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);

It works great.....